# Jquery Image object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand this piece of JQuery.

```
$.fn.imageCrop = function(customOptions) {
        //Iterate over each object
        this.each(function() {
            var currentObject = this,
                image = new Image();

            // And attach imageCrop when the object is loaded
            image.onload = function() {
                $.imageCrop(currentObject, customOptions);
            };

            // Reset the src because cached images don't fire load sometimes
            image.src = currentObject.src;
        });

        // Unless the plug-in is returning an intrinsic value, always have the
        // function return the 'this' keyword to maintain chainability
        return this;
    };
```

What I can't understand is that a new and therefore empty Image object is created, then an onload method is added to the image and then the image.src is manually reset in case it doesn't fire a reload. But why would it fire a reload at all? It's just an empty image object with no relation to anything. Is is somehow automatically linked to currentObject?

Comment: I believe assigning a value to image.src triggers the load of the image. They probably didn't set the src when the image object is created because cached images would load before they handler was assigned. This way, the onload will surely fire after the handler is assigned. Pure guesswork though :).

Comment: I was thinking something like this, but it doesn't make sense saying they';re resetting src when it hasn't been set. It is implying currentObject and image are already somehow linked.

Comment: I see it that `$.imageCrop` needs the image to be loaded, so it is executed when the image object is loaded.  The comment above the line that sets `src` is not clear enough.  It should explain that you set `src` there, and not before `onload` because if the image has previously been loaded (and is therefore cached), `onload` may not fire.  Setting `src` *after* you create the `onload` handler stops that happening.  It's just an unclear (bad) comment.

Comment: Ahh I see, and hence the need for the second Image object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code with my comments, see if it helps. The src has to be set to wait for the event

```
    //this is a jquery plugin,
//jquery plugins start this way 
//so you could select $('img').imageCrop();
$.fn.imageCrop = function(customOptions) {
    //Iterate over each object
    this.each(function() {
        //keeps the current iterated object in a variable
        //current image will be kept in this var untill the next loop
        var currentObject = this,
        //creates a new Image object    
        image = new Image();
        // And attach imageCrop when the object is loaded
        //correct
        image.onload = function() {
            $.imageCrop(currentObject, customOptions);
        };
        //sets the src to wait for the onload event up here ^
        image.src = currentObject.src;
    });
    // Unless the plug-in is returning an intrinsic value, always have the
    // function return the 'this' keyword to maintain chainability
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused. If currentObject is an Image object then why do we need to create a second Image object to attach imagecrop to? Why not just attach it to currentObject? And why do the original comments refer to resetting the src property of the new Image object if it hasn't been previously set?

Comment: Creating a "new Image()" creates an "empty" object, thus letting us take control of the loading part, meanwhile if you attach it to the original, the event might not get fired. You just have to load it again.